# Word Counter Program in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm taking a course on C++ and have been given an assignment as follows:

> This program inputs a manuscript in text form from standard input device and analyzes the 
>   lengths of all the words encountered. Only alphabetic characters, numbers and apostrophes 
>   within a word contribute to the word length.

The professor has given me a little help with structure, yet I'm still struggling. Mainly with getting the correct location of the array to increment each time the corresponding length is returned from the the WordLength function. The plan is to use array elements 1-15 and any words over 15 characters long will just go in the 15 element of the array. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int WordLength();
void DisplayCount(int wordCount[]);

void main()
{
    int L;
    int Num_of_Char[16]={0};
    L=WordLength();
    while (L)
    {
        L=WordLength();
        Num_of_Char[L]+=1;
    }

    DisplayCount(Num_of_Char);
}

/***************************************WordLength*******************************************
*   Action:         Analyzes the text that has been entered and decides what is and isn't   *
*                   a word (mainly by separating words by whitespaces and not accepting     *
*                   most punctuation as part of a word with the exception of hyphens which  *
*                   carry a partial word to the next line as well as apostrophes.           *
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:                                                                                 *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:                                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:        The length of each word.                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:                                                                           *
*********************************************************************************************/
int WordLength()
{
    char ch[500];
    int End_Of_Word=0, Length=0, i=0;

    cout<<"Please enter some text:\n";
    cin.get(ch,500);

    while((!cin.eof)&&(!End_Of_Word))
    {
        if((i==0)&&(isspace(ch[i])))
        {
            ++i;
        }
        else if(isalnum(ch[i]))
        {
            ++Length;
            ++i;
        }
        else if ((ch[i]=='\'')&&((ch[i-1]=='s')||(ch[i-1]=='S'))&&(isspace(ch[i+1])))   //accounts for plural possessive of a word
        {
            ++Length;
            ++i;
        }
        else if ((ch[i]=='\'')&&((ch[i+1]=='s')||(ch[i+1]=='S')))   //accounts for single possessive of a word and keeps the hyphen as part of the word
        {
            ++Length;
            ++i;
        }
        else if((isspace(ch[i]))||(ispunct(ch[i]))||(ch[i]=='\0'))
        {
            ++End_Of_Word;
        }
        return Length;
    }
}

/***************************************DisplayCount*****************************************
*   Action:         Displays how many words have a specific character count between 1 and   *
*                   15 characters. Then displays the average word character size.           *
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:         wordArray, which points to the array that holds the count of each word's*
*                   character size.                                                         *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:        Displays the array contents in a grid style as well as an average       *
*                   word size based on the contents of the array.                           *
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:                                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:   wordArray points to an int array                                        *
*********************************************************************************************/
void DisplayCount(int wordArray[])
{
    double sum = 0;
    cout<<"\tWord Length\t\t"<<"Frequency\n";
    cout<<"\t-----------\t\t"<<"---------\n";

    for(int i=1; i<16; i++) 
    {
        cout<<"\t     "<<i<<"\t\t\t    "<<wordArray[i]<<endl;   //Displays the contents of each element
        sum+=(i*wordArray[i]);  //Keeps a running total of contents of array
    }

    cout<<"\tAverage word length:  "<<sum/(15)<<endl;       //Displays the average word length
}
```

Any help, would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @bikram990: This is a wrong perception. C++ is not just meant for OOP; [it's a multi-paradigm language](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#multiparadigm) which can be used for different programming styles.

Comment: @legends2k i agree with that but the beauty of c++ is OOP.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that your `WordLength()` function is returning the length after a single iteration of the loop, so it's always 1. You need to put the return statement outside of the loop.

There is also at least one other problem. The first word is not getting counted because you never save the result of the first call to `WordLength()`.

Finally, you also are prompting the user to enter their text each time, and are only getting the length of the first word they enter in their string. You probably want to get the string before calling `WordLength()` the first time.

Comment: I think the intent is to generate a histogram. So you'll end up with a count of how many words have a single letter, how many have 2, etc. So I think that part is correct, unless I've misunderstood the original intent.

Comment: that got rid of the errors, but now, I just get a blank terminal window when I run it through the debugger. Would you like me to post my updated code?